# sys.indexes - type column

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, sql-server-2022

According to official documentation of [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), `type = 2 -->Nonclustered rowstore (B-tree)`. But the line 4 of the following example taken from online [here](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-all-indexes-in-the-database) is showing `type = 2 -->Nonclustered unique`. Question: Does type =2 implies Nonclustered unique index. Why the author is using `unique` in line 4 below?

```
select i.[name] as index_name,
    substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns],
    case when i.[type] = 1 then 'Clustered index'
        when i.[type] = 2 then 'Nonclustered unique index'
        when i.[type] = 3 then 'XML index'
        when i.[type] = 4 then 'Spatial index'
        when i.[type] = 5 then 'Clustered columnstore index'
        when i.[type] = 6 then 'Nonclustered columnstore index'
        when i.[type] = 7 then 'Nonclustered hash index'
        end as index_type,
    case when i.is_unique = 1 then 'Unique'
        else 'Not unique' end as [unique],
    schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
    case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
        when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
        end as [object_type]
from sys.objects t
    inner join sys.indexes i
        on t.object_id = i.object_id
    cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                    from sys.index_columns ic
                        inner join sys.columns col
                            on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                            and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                    where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                            order by key_ordinal
                            for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
where t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
and index_id > 0
order by i.[name]
```

Comment: You can now use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) instead of FOR XML.

Answer (score 3):

> Does type =2 implies Nonclustered unique index. Why the author is using unique in line 4 below?

The excerpt below from the [sys.indexes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) shows type 2 is a non-clustered rowstore index. Type alone does not indicate whether the index is unique or non-unique. The separate `is_unique` column specifies if the index is unique.

> Type of index:
>
> 0 = Heap
> 1 = Clustered rowstore (B-tree)
> 2 = Nonclustered rowstore (B-tree)
> 3 = XML
> 4 = Spatial
> 5 = Clustered columnstore index. Applies to: SQL Server 2014 (12.x)
> and later.
> 6 = Nonclustered columnstore index. Applies to: SQL Server 2012 (11.x)
> and later.
> 7 = Nonclustered hash index. Applies to: SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and
> later.

I cannot say why the author specified unique in the description for type 2. My guess it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the table sys.indexes has a different column that is called is_unique and only according to it's value you can know if it is a unique index or none unique index.  The person that wrote the query also knows it, because at the 11th line he/she also checks for the value of is_unique column in order to specify this property.  My guess is that he/she made a mistake at the string when they wrote 'Nonclustered unique index'.  The fact that they don't have another value for noclustered none unique index can also imply that it was a mistake.

Adi